# Не работает кэширование статики nginx для поддоменов

Tags: nginx, laravel, кэширование

Nginx не кэширует статику для поддоменов. Сервис pagespeed показывает, что кэш включён, но при изменении файла берётся обновлённый код с сервера, а не из кэша браузера.

> **Response Headers**
>  Cache-Control:public
>   Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
>  Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>  Content-Type:text/css
>  Date:Mon, 23 May
>   2016 12:00:31 GMT
>  Expires:Wed, 22 Jun 2016 12:00:31 GMT
>   Last-Modified:Mon, 23 May 2016 11:59:30 GMT
>  Server:nginx/1.4.6
>   (Ubuntu)
>  Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>  Vary:Accept-Encoding

**Настройки nginx**

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name site.ru;
    root /home/site/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;

    client_max_body_size       10m;
    client_body_buffer_size    128k;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 30;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(css)$
    {
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/css(/.+)$) {
            set $modify_request_uri $1;
            return 301 $scheme://css.site.ru$modify_request_uri;
        }
    }
}

server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name css.site.ru;
    root /home/site/public/css;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/css.site.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/css.site.error.log;
    location ~* {
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

---

Отвечаю на комментарий от norbornen

if_modified_since off и скрыть заголовок Last-Modified

> **Response Headers**
>  Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
>  Cache-Control:public
>  Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>  Content-Type:text/css
>  Date:Mon, 23 May
>   2016 13:26:54 GMT
>  Expires:Wed, 22 Jun 2016 13:26:54 GMT
>   Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
>  Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>   Vary:Accept-Encoding

Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Все верно, файл же на сервере был изменен!

Comment: нужно чтобы он отдавался из кэша браузера, пока не истечёт время в заголовке Expires

Comment: Какую спецификацию HTTP используете?

Comment: `if_modified_since off` и скрыть заголовок Last-Modified

Comment: И как вы это проверяете? Жмёте f5?

Comment: Ну так F5 мягко, но всё равно принуждает браузер перезапросить все ресурсы. Правильный способ: открыть страницу в новой вкладке.

Answer (score 1):

Может поможет:

```
# кеширование в браузере на стороне пользователя
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>

# Cache-Control
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
# 30 дней
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
# 30 дней
<filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
# 2 дня
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
# 1 день
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>

#Запрет отдачи HTTP-заголовков Vary браузерам семейства MSIE
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" force-no-vary
</IfModule>
```

[Первоисточник](http://www.sysmasters.net/kb/ispolzovanie-kesha-na-storone-brauzera-apache/)

Comment: я использую nginx + php-fpm без apache